# Library for JSP parsing and manipulation

Tags: parsing, jsoup, jsp-tags

I am trying to parse a bunch of JSP files and find places with hardcoded strings. E.g.

```
<h:outputText value="I am hardcoded" styleClass="someClass" />
<my:customTag value="I am hardcoded too" />
```

Currently I am using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do so. It seems great as an HTML parser, however if I make changes to the document and write it out to a file all of the case sensitive JSF tags and attributes are changed to lowercase. Are there any Java libraries that can parse a JSP file, let me modify some attribute values, and let me write out the JSP?

Or better yet is there a way to tell [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) not to change the casing of my elements and attributes?

Comment: I just took the jsoup source code and removed all `toLowerCase()` and that seemed to fix my problems. Might not be the optimal solution but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the case for other people, but it turns out replacing all of the `toLowerCase()` calls in [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) worked well enough for me.