# Can jsp be parsed with Jsoup ?

Tags: jsp, jsoup

Is there a possiblity for parsing jsp with jsoup?

if not please suggest a parser for doing it in java

Answer (score 4):

Yes but it's not great.

There are a few workarounds for using Jsoup

- [Library for JSP parsing and manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519394/library-for-jsp-parsing-and-manipulation)
- [JSP and HTML parser for JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139083/jsp-and-html-parser-for-java)

[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) claims it can parse server-side tags but I've never used it.

This [post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/hacking-jasper-to-get-object-model-of.html) describes how you can use the [Jasper JSP compiler](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) from Tomcat.